# ISBN API connection - Forbidden Message

Tags: php, api

I just subscribe to [Isbndb.com](https://isbndb.com/). I have my Api key but when i try to test the API with [the PHP sample code](https://isbndb.com/apidocs#examples). I have the following error message :

> {"message":"Forbidden"}

I have  tried to do it with guzzlehttp too and i have a HTTP code error 403. Same with the "try it out" button in the documentation.

Does anyone has a idea or an hint? I tried to contact the support but no anwsers from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from the support. The reason why it wasn't working : my API key wasn't activated.

This is the code i use now with guzzle.

```
    $url = '/book/' .$isbn;
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => $this->config['url'],
    ]);
    $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'X-API-Key' => $this->config['key']
        ]
    ]);

    $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

Check in your account if you have the **Daily calls allowed** showing your limit if not try to contact them directly on : support@isbndb.com.